# Queryset returning modelinstances of manytomany relationship?

Tags: django

Say I have 2 classes as:

```
class Bar(models.Model):
   prop = IntegerField()

class Foo(models.Model):
   bar = ManyToManyField(Bar)
```

I want to return a QuerySet containing model instances of bar that
match the query:

```
QuerySetOfFoos.objects.filter(bar__prop__gt=0)
```

Is there an easy way to do this?  I know that in the model instance I
could do foo.bar_set but not sure how to do it over all of the
original QuerySet...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get a QuerySet of Bars, you need to start with the Bar manager, i.e. Bar.objects. This will work:

```
Bar.objects.filter(foo__in=QuerySetOfFoos, prop__gt=0)
```

Ideally, you should simply include whatever parameters were used to get QuerySetOfFoos in your query. For example, if your Foos had "group" and "rank" fields, and you wanted all Bars for Foos with group "members" and rank > 10, you would do:

```
Bar.objects.filter(foo__group='members', foo__rank__gt=10, prop__gt=0)
```

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for, m2m__in, as well as just recalling that you can think of the m2m relationship from both directions which is something that slips my mind occasionally.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this:

```
Bar.objects.filter(foo__bar__prop__gt = 0)
```

?

Comment: Not quite since that would be from all Bars, not just those bars that are in a M2M with the queryset 'QuerySetOfFoos' however that is a handy thing to know!